# Obtain GPS Coordinates from A3 Flight Controller using SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I am having a hard time finding any documentation on what I am trying to accomplish.

Basically, all I need to do is set up the A3 flight controller to output the GPS coordinates every defined interval through the local SBus port. When connected in Assistant 2, it looks like you can map the A3 output to a number of different functions, including SDK 1-8 which can be defined through code using the onboard SDK.

[image]

Here's where I am a bit confused, however. In the same software, if you click on the SDK tab, you can get to a window where you can define what is output, baud rates, etc..:

[image]

So my question is, when you define all the output frequencies and settings in the SDK tab, does this information automatically get output to all of the F5-F8 ports that are set to SDK? Basically, I am simply trying to obtain the coordinates so if there is a way to do it without writing code, this would be ideal.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some trial and error, I was able to determine that the parameters defined in the Data and Transmission Rates page are sent through the API port on the A3. After defining the desired frequency, I am able to get the position directly from this port without having to write any code. Hopefully this helps someone else that has the same question.